# Separar dados de vários formulários com FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, formdata

Teria como enviar alguns formularios ao mesmo tempo com *FormData*?

Por exemplo, cada produto vai ter tamanhos e imagens. Teria como separar cada produto em um array e enviar ao mesmo tempo para a página PHP, para assim eu poder percorrer eles com um *foreach* e fazer o cadastro.

Tentei assim, mas ele mistura os dados de todos produtos, invés de separar:

```
    var dados = new FormData();

    $('.copiar-elemento').each(function() {
        $(this).find("select[name*='tamanho']").each(function(index, element) {
            dados.append('cores[tamanhos][]', element.value);
        });

        $(this).find('input:file').each(function(index, element) {
            dados.append('cores[imagens][]', element.files[0]);
        });
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: $('#form-produto').attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: dados,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A ordenação não importa, uma vez que o seu tratamento via PHP irá reorganizar, conforme o *name de cada POST*, o array.

Comment: O único fator importante é saber se os dados estão sendo enviados corretamente, de acordo com cada name, na saída.

Comment: Possui uma *foto/print* do *request*, com as informações geradas?

Comment: Coloquei o print na pergunta. Sabe ali onde tem o "GG" e "M"? O GG pertence a um produto e o M pertence a outro. Tenho que criar um indice "cores" para cada produto.

Comment: OBS: O indice "titulo" vai ser o mesmo para todos produtos, entao nao precisa ficar dentro do "cores", essa parte esta correta.

Comment: O problema é que ele está criando apenas um "cores" e colocando todos os dados dentro desse, invés de separar.

Comment: O problema está na sua lógica. Uma vez que você cria um *name request*, ele é único. Você deveria fazer algo como: cores_imagens e cores_tamanhos para poder especificar melhor.

Comment: Acriação das imagens e tamanhos está correta, o problema é separar os produtos. Tinha que gerar algo nesse estilo: cores ['imagens' => ['imagem1', 'imagem2'], 'tamanhos' => ['m', 'G']], cores ['imagens' => ['imagem3', 'imagem4'], 'tamanhos' => ['P', 'GG']]

Comment: Então faca: 'cores[imagens][ '+index+' ]'

Comment: Cara, era isso mesmo. Valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: Vou postar a resposta, assinale como concluída.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme o comentário, a montagem do *append* deveria ser:

```
 'cores[' + index + '][imagens][]
 'cores[' + index + '][tamanhos][]
```

....

Comment: Só precisei fazer uma pequena alteração: 'cores[' + index + '][tamanhos][]